# CSS help needed to make the Image go to the top

Tags: html, css

I have a table that is split into 3. My problem is I have content on the left side and pic on the right side. When I open the page the pic is starting in the middle of the page I need the pic to be displayed at the top of the page. How can I do that?

```
       <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
        <td > 
        <table> Lots of Content </table>

        </td>

        <td width ="10%">
          <table> Empty table (that gives space between left content and right image                         </table>

           </td>

        <td width = "20%">
        <table width="100%">
             <tr>
             <td> <Asp:Image Runat="server" Id="Image" align="top"> </td>
             </tr>



              </table> </td>
          </tr>
           </table>
```

Comment: The best way would be getting rid of the tables and making a css layout

Comment: Using tables to format a layout and creating a table to hold the image is pointless.  just drop the image in the td.  Or better yet stop using the table to format your layout and use divs and then position the image absolute or relative top depending on the effect you want

Comment: Tables for layout are the wrong way to make a page. Tables are for tabular data only.

Comment: It is not something I created. I am maintaining an existing page and I have to find a way to fix it using somefix. I don't have the permissions to rebuild the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this page to figure out what kind of positioning you want (not sure from post) http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

And then embed the code like this:

```
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
 img
  {
  [Style properties you pic]
  }
 </style>
</head>
```

Or consult [css_howto](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) and use a proper CSS file for you entire page layout (no more tables)

Comment: I started creating css to that page. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want / need to keep the existing structure and look for a quick and dirty fix, then set the position of the Image to absolute and with top and left position it exactly where you want.

Comment: isn't that exactly what he wanted? The img at the top of the page?

Comment: sorry Sven, I was thinking top of the td - should have read more closely!

Comment: np. Happens to me all the time ;)

Comment: Can you perhaps give the css or inline css of what exactly you have done?

Comment: You should avoid statements like it didn't work. What didn't work? Your toaster? Provide details regarding how it doesn't work or what you have done to attempt it. This will allow for more useful and informed responses.

Answer (score 0):

that's easy... here's the hack... add a class to the td

```
.positionhack {position:relative}
```

then on the image

```
 .positionTop {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is wrong. With this "hack" he changes absolute nothing in the rendered position of the image.